# How did Nick figure out the fourth clue in "Gone Girl"?

Tags: gillian-flynn, gone-girl

The fourth clue read:

> Picture me: I’m a girl who is very bad
>   I need to be punished, and by punished, I mean had
>   It’s where you store goodies for anniversary five
>   Pardon me if this is getting contrived!
>   A good time was had right here at sunny midday
>   Then out for a cocktail, all so terribly gay.
>   So run there right now, full of sweet sighs,
>   And open the door for your big surprise.

How did Nick figure out that "*Goodies would be something made of wood. To punish is to take someone to the woodshed. It was the woodshed behind my sister’s house – a place to stow lawn-mower parts and rusty tools*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tradition in the U.S. and U.K. of [what kind of gifts to give couples on each anniversary.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_anniversary#Traditional_and_modern_anniversary_gifts) Fifth anniversary is wood. (this is also the source of calling a 25th anniversary "silver" and a 50th "gold.")

"Taking someone out to the woodshed" is an [old American idiom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trip_to_the_woodshed) for giving a child a spanking or beating as punishment, done privately (out behind the woodshed, where the parent could beat the child and the child's cries wouldn't be heard by the rest of the family).